# An arrowed line with a switch in the middle

Tags: tikz-arrows, circuitikz

I wanted to draw an arrowed line but with a switch in the middle. What I currently use is this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=1pt] (-0.3,-.5) to[cspst] (-0.3,-1.5); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output has a switch in the middle but without any arrow. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) in future, rather than code fragments. It makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. Sorry, I wasn't familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was that you could do this simply by adding `->` to the draw statement but, as shown below, this doesn't produce the desired output. Next I tried doing the switch and the arrow as a decoration with two markings, but I could not see how to use the switch switch `cspst` as a decoration. I think that it should be possible to do it this way in which case it would be much cleaner.

The code below adds the arrow tip using a decoration that is added using `addarrow` to produce:

[image]

The lefthand example shows that adding `->` does not work. The righthand arrow is hopefully what is wanted. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,decorations}

\tikzset{% define addarrow decoration
    addarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                     postaction={decorate}}
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=1pt,->] (-0.3,-.5) to[cspst] ++(0,-1.5);       % bad
    \draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (2.3,-.5) to[cspst] ++(0,-1.5);  % good
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very beautiful :)